# Script to be activated if web page changes

Tags: applescript, web-browsing

I'm looking for a way to have a script running on my desktop that will check a certain webpage for changes every `x` seconds, and if a change is made, it gives me an alert. I understand that with high-end websites, some changes will be made almost constantly, but what I'm looking for monitoring now is a bare-bones HTML page that I'm waiting for a link to show up on. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
Would it be a command to download the html and store it, and then a recurring download-and-check command?

Comment: Would a shell script (running in Terminal) be an option as well?

Comment: @patrix Yes, it would.

Comment: In case you want to try yourself, look at `curl` and `diff` (`man curl` and `man diff` in Terminal) and read any Bash shell programming tutorial.

Comment: The part where this specifies to parse a multitude of HTML documents and programmatically determine if this constitutes a "change" would be better suited on StackOverflow.com. An edited question on how to automate the download of one URL to a file would seem to be on topic since Automator allows that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Save this as `~/bin/example` and run `chmod +x ~/bin/example`. (Edited to only check the modification date from the header.)

```
#!/bin/bash

url=http://www.iana.org/domains/example
tempdir=~/Library/Caches/scripts
temp=$tempdir/example
mkdir -p $tempdir
modified=$(curl -sI "$url" | grep ^Last-Modified)
if [[ -f "$temp" && "$modified" != "$(cat $temp)" ]]; then
    terminal-notifier -message 'Example changed'
fi
printf %s "$modified" > $temp
```

To run it every 15 minutes, add `*/15 * * * * ~/bin/example` to crontab (`EDITOR=nano crontab -e`).

[terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) can be installed with `sudo gem install terminal-notifier`.

You could also run it every five seconds in a shell window:

```
while :; do ~/bin/example; sleep 5; done
```

Comment: If the server publishes an ETag or Last-Modified header, you wouldn't even need to download the whole page but only the headers reducing resource wasting on both sides.

Comment: Where is "$tmp/example" fetched from the web once to act as a baseline?

Comment: Sorry to be picky but $temp still needs to be initialized (e.g. by running `curl -sI "$url" | grep ^Last-Modified > "$temp"`)

Comment: @patrix I forgot that -f check from the first revisions, thanks.

Comment: So...I don't like using code I don't understand. I'll accept this as the answer, but sometime could someone walk me through how it works in chat?